# Tripple list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have that code:

```
tt = []

for i in cp:
    for ii in i:
        for iii in all_numbers:
            if ii == iii[0]:
                tt.append([i, iii[1]])
```

How can I make the same list using comprehension?

Comment: Would probably be very hard to read as a list comprehension

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: If you make `iii` into a dictionary, you can probably make this a lot more efficient.

Comment: for some countings with lists :) I dont want to create one more variable only for one using.

Comment: @Blckknght, I dont need a dictionary because I need to have indexes

Comment: I think I described it incorrectly, it's `all_numbers` that should be a dict, mapping between potential `ii` values and the values you put in your `tt` list. Rather than looping over the various `iii` pairs, you just look up the first one as a key into the dictionary to get the values, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically keep the `for` clauses in the same order.

```
tt = [[i,iii[1] for i in cp for ii in i for iii in all_numbers if ii == iii[0]]
```

Comment: thanx a lot. i needed an example to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Roberts has given you the direct translation of your nested loops into a list comprehension. I wanted to supplement that answer by proposing that your original code could be improved by changing the innermost loop into a dictionary lookup:

```
num_dict = dict(all_nums)   # map from iii[0] to iii[1] values
tt = []
for i in cp:
    for ii in i:
        if ii in num_dict:
            tt.append([i, num_dict[ii]])

# or tt = [[i, num_dict[ii]] for i in cp for ii in i if ii in num_dict]
```

This makes some assumptions about your data, such as that `all_nums` items have exactly two values (where your original code could allow for more). The version of the code above also assumes that there are no duplicate keys (e.g. that each inner loop of your original code would only find at most one match per `iii` value). If that's not true, you'd need a slightly more sophisticated conversion of the data into a dictionary and then slightly different code (with a new inner loop) to handle the values:

```
num_dict = {}  # now we map to a list of values, without assuming uniqueness
for key, *values in all_nums:
    num_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(values)

tt = []
for i in cp:
    for ii in i:
        for iii, *rest in num_dict.get(ii, []):
            tt.append([i, iii])

# or tt = [[i, iii] for i in cp for ii in i for iii, *rest in num_dict.get(ii, [])]
```